# Access grub menu on Ubuntu Core 18.04 (Raspberry Pi 4)

Tags: raspberrypi, grubrescue

I have installed Ubuntu Core 18.04 on raspberry pi a few months ago with NextCloud.

I turned it on again yesterday. After a few minutes on, it restarted. I guess it did automatic updates (which is weird to me since i didnt ask for it, but I'm a first time user of Ubuntu).

Anyway, now the system is stuck at the loading screen with the Ubuntu logo core logo in the middle.

The trick [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time), to get into the grub menu with <kbd>Esc</kbd> button or <kbd>1</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> doesn't work for me.
I realize now that probably the system I created does not contain grub menu recovery mode.

Any other ideas? or my only solution is to restart the whole installation process? I'm gonna lose my data on NextCloud if I do that, but if that's the only way...

can you recommend me of an installer for ubuntu that will not update itself automatically, or will not break in a similar manner in the future?

Comment: What are you using? I can not find any info on a core 21, 20 is the latest.  In the title you call it core 21.04 which is a version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Ubuntu releases using the *year* format are different products to those using the *year.month* format. Ubuntu Core 20 is the latest *snap* only release, so if you've a Ubuntu Core 21 - I'd check what you actually have as it's likely you've got a forgery, or at least not what you expected.  21 (2021 release) is very different to 21.04 (2021-April release) for example as they signify different systems; only the 21.04 uses *deb* packages and thus `apt` & `dpkg` commands as well as `snap` commands; where 21 uses `snap` commands only.

Comment: Did you mean Ubuntu server 21.04 (the CLI version)?

Comment: apologies. you guys are right. i installed ubuntu core 18.04. not 21.

Answer (score 2):

There are several "wrong assumptions" in your post.

1. There is nothing called Ubuntu Core 18.04. There is Ubuntu Core 18, and the latest core release is Ubuntu Core 20.
2. The Raspberry Pi images (of either Core or LTS) does not include GRUB at all (it uses u-boot instead).

So what you're asking is actually not possible, since there should be no GRUB in your installation.

I don't actually know if the Raspberry Pi can support GRUB at all.

Comment: hi arthur,
you are right.
1. i had a mistake. i installed ubuntu core 18.04. not 21. with snap and nextcloud. on raspberry pi 4.
2. i realize that you are right about this as well. the pi doesn't support grub as default. 
so what can I do to fix the ubuntu on the device? 
what can I do to make sure something like this doesn't happen again?